# How to recompute the last operation symbolically?

Tags: calc

In symbolic mode I can type `N` to get the numerical value of the last expression: `2 Q` pushes `sqrt(2)`, at that point `N` pushes `1.414…`. What's the quickest way to do the opposite? I.e., after having entered `2 Q` in decimal approximation mode, what's the quickest way to get `sqrt(2)`?

(Edit) In other words, what I am looking for is a functionality similar to that of the <kbd>S⇔D</kbd> button of some calculators, i.e. turn a result that was approximated back into a symbolic expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, converting from a floating point number to an arbitrary symbolic expression is difficult (and technically impossible to do perfectly).  So, if you want to convert 1.41421356237 into `sqrt(2)` then you are probably out of luck inside Emacs.  You can check http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html for an "Inverse Symbolic Calculator".  Play around with it to see why it might be hard.  :)  Converting to a fraction is simpler and can be done with `c F`.

But maybe you're just looking for a way to undo and then redo in symbolic mode?  For that you can do

- `U` — undo
- `m s` — turn on symbolic mode
- `Q` — or whatever the last command was
- `m s` — turn symbolic mode back off (if desired)

You could probably also write a function that would turn on `calc-symbolic-mode` for just the next command, but I'm not sure how helpful that would be.

Comment: _> converting from a floating point number to an arbitrary symbolic expression is difficult_ My question wasn't really clear about it but I'm not looking for a way to convert any FP number to an expression. What I'm looking for basically is the same as what the `S⇔D` button of some calculators does, i.e. turn the last result back into a symbolic expression from a decimal approximation. I've just started using Calc so I expected there to be some way to do it that I didn't know about. The undo thing is exactly that, thanks :-)